# Silverstripe FulltextSearchable use Operators

Tags: full-text-search, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I've implemented a search page using the fullTextSearch feature in SilverStripe.  It seems to work ok.

How can I use search operators like AND(+) and NOT(-) in my search terms.  It is defaulting to OR.

It seems this is supported by MySql, using Boolean Mode.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html